# where is a coaxial cable shield connected to ground

Tags: networking, transmission

I am reading about coaxial cable it is written that coaxial cable has a metallic shield that protects it from interference and it should be grounded but when i see the wires that are connected to our cable tv i don't see that it is grounded it is just left like that and the inner core wire is connected.So then where is it grounded and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Coaxial Cable does not need to be grounded to use for general TV purposes, however if you are using an antenna mast it is required that you use a Ground Electrode System (GES). Link is below:

http://support.channelmaster.com/hc/en-us/articles/200383635-Do-I-need-to-ground-my-antenna-and-coaxial-cable-